# is iOS sdk available for download?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

i want to study iOS sdk from home where i do not have access to internet. Is there anyway in which i can download iOS sdk(hopefully free of cost). if so, what may be the size of the sdk... Thanku...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you register for a free ADC account you can download the SDK free from [Apple's iOS Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios). The file is about 4GB, so the download will take a while.

The main restriction of a free account is you can't run your new app on a device. You can only run in the simulator until you join the paid iOS developer program for $99/year.

Also, there is a bit of a learning curve when you want to step up running on a device, but as embedded systems go, it is really pretty easy.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's available for download at apple's developer website: http://developer.apple.com/

Size of SDK is over 3.5G.